# useEffect to set value of TextField not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, material-ui

I'm attempting to use `useEffect` to set the initial value of a MUI `TextField` on load. The value is being pulled from a database. This works the majority of the time however in some cases the `useEffect` **does not** correctly update the value of the `textfield` and it is just blank.

**My Question: How can I change my code to make sure that the data being pulled from useEffect always sets the initial value of a textfield on load?**

```
const [introText, setIntroText] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchResults = async () => {
    const result = await axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://server.site.com/userData",
      withCredentials: true,
    });
    setIntroText(result.data.introEssayText);
  };

  fetchResults();
}, []);

<TextField
  onChange={(e) => setIntroText(e.target.value)}
  value={introText}
  onInput={handleUpdatedIntro}
/>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"This works the majority of the time however in some cases the `useEffect` does not correctly update the value of the `textfield` and it is just blank"*.

Make sure `result.data.introEssayText` is not empty for all use cases.

Other than that, having

```
const [introText, setIntroText] = useState()
```

would trigger the below warning for a normal `input` which I believe `TextField` would fall back to.

> Warning: a component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components

Instead use

```
const [introText, setIntroText] = useState("")
```

so the initial value of the input is `""` instead of `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks @yousoumar! I implemented all of this. "Make sure result.data.introEssayText is not empty for all use cases" was good advice as I realized I did not have an async/await on the app.get("/userData...  route which could have caused the issue I believe

Comment: My pleasure @AndrewLeonardi. Yeah it could if you are using `await` in it. Let me know if it works !